# Why do I get so many unsolicited Facebook friend requests?

Tags: facebook, friends, facebook-friend-request

At least once a day, I get a Facebook friend request from someone I don't know, most likely a fake account, from people all over the world.

Does it happen to everyone, or am I somehow targeted?
Is there a way to reduce this?

Comment: As to "why", that's difficult to know. Do you have a common name? Is your profile picture obviously female?

Comment: Pnuts I don't really want to restrict legitimate people I meet to look me up.

Comment: AI E: my name is not common at all. Should I understand from you then that this is not common for other Facebook users?

Comment: I can't speak to other Facebook users, but I can't remember the last time I got a friend request from someone I don't know. Then again, I think I have that restricted to "friends of friends".

Comment: Ok I guess I'll do friends of friends